Can't install Windows 11, version 24H2 due to conflict with ExplorerPatcher
I have ExplorerPatcher installed and it seems to be preventing Windows 11 24H2 from being installed:

Anything I can do about this (other than either uninstall ExplorerPatcher or wait and see if Windows changes this policy)?
Current version of Windows: 

Have you "Checked with your software provider for an updated version"?

@grawity: Yeash

@user2071051 Why do you think that the issue's that software? Did you already try out uninstalling one and then upgrading Windows to be sure that the issue's really the one?

@JorgeLuiz - Certain start menu/file explorer "enhancers" are already known to prevent the patch because they do things in ways that Microsoft no longer supports. ExplorerPatcher is one such, as you could have easily discovered through a Google Search.

You have three choices, none of which appear to be acceptable based on the way you asked the question:

Uninstall ExplorerPatcher and get the Windows update.
Wait and hope that the publisher of ExplorerPatcher will come up with a version that Microsoft will find acceptable.
Keep ExplorerPatcher and get bugged about it every time Windows wants to upgrade. Don't rule out the possibility that a future Windows update may forcibly remove ExplorerPatcher as malware.

Conceivably, you could look for an add-on that gives you the same functionality as ExplorerPatcher, but which does it in a way that doesn't block the update. The only ones I'm aware of are neither libre nor gratis.

Instructions directly from ExplorerPatch recommend to uninstall ExplorerPatch before installing 24H2

@Ramhound - after which I've heard reports that you can't reinstall it under 24H2.
